# Jupyter Notebook | Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python's latest version:

```
Python 3.10.2
```

I have installed Jupyter Notebook by using.

```
pip install jupyter
```

Later I want to start Jupiter notebook in cmd by writing:

```
Jupyter notebook
```

Previously it's working fine and smooth. The next day there occur a couple of errors. Here are some screenshots and text of the command window.

[This is the first error that I recieve at begining][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1L4z.png

[After closing the program this error apperas][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B22k0.png

[Its the camand window about jupyter][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g71x7.png

Here is the text of comand window:

```
[W 20:36:29.590 NotebookApp] Notebook Desktop/AI Projects/NLP/Untitled.ipynb is not trusted
Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[I 20:36:29.929 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 56297648-4e26-4a5b-8d25-1f990c6e422b, name: 
python3
Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Exception in thread IOPub:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
File "C:\Users\ABDUL RAUF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 
1009, in _bootstrap_innerself.run()
File "C:\Users\ABDUL RAUF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 
946, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ABDUL RAUF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 82, in _thread_main
self.io_loop.start()
File "C:\Users\ABDUL RAUF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
```

Versions of jupyter Notebook：

```
jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.1.1
ipykernel        : 6.9.2
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.1.2
jupyter_core     : 4.9.2
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.4.4
nbformat         : 5.2.0
notebook         : 6.4.10
qtconsole        : 5.2.2
traitlets        : 5.1.1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
netsh winsock reset
```

fixes the issue for me. It seems like there is some VPN software modified your default winsock settings that bugged pyzmq.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to winsock2 unresolved issue on Windows (When you installed some VPN program, and it modified some default winsock settings):
[microsoft/WSL#4177](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4177)

You can execute [NoLsp.exe](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/www.proxifier.com/tmp/Test20200228/NoLsp.exe) with jupyter related EXE files to do the fix, for example:

```
NoLsp.exe "C:\Users\scruel\miniconda3\envs\py310-torch\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe"
NoLsp.exe "C:\Users\scruel\miniconda3\envs\py310-torch\Scripts\jupyter.exe"
NoLsp.exe "C:\Users\scruel\miniconda3\envs\py310-torch\python.exe"
```

You can also check the script I created for one-click usage:
https://gist.github.com/scruel/73b3b9ac436b71703ee40bca6791c2aa

Notice:

`netsh winsock reset` will cause your VPN to stop working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the answer
`netsh winsock reset`
works for me, thank you.

In addition, I found that downgrading pyzmq to 19.0.2 can also work, but using this method restricts me to only use python3.7 and 3.8.

Maybe the developers didn't notice this VPN problem when they realease the new version.

Comment: Glad everything is working. It took me a year to find this solution as well.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33351125)