# Jupyter Notebook Could not Connect to Kernel upon Start

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Issue occurred today when I noticed my anaconda navigator exited without me closing it. I was using Jupyter notebook without problem before but when I tried to relaunch it today, I was presented with this error message:

"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

Trying to launch it from command line resulted in the following log:

```
[I 10:13:33.456 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\arena
[I 10:13:33.456 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 10:13:33.456 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=c5a68051d3d81fc964448454cd0310f81f5b4366ed6bd5ad
[I 10:13:33.456 NotebookApp] or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=c5a68051d3d81fc964448454cd0310f81f5b4366ed6bd5ad
[I 10:13:33.456 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:13:33.476 NotebookApp]

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///C:/Users/arena/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-7316-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8888/?token=c5a68051d3d81fc964448454cd0310f81f5b4366ed6bd5ad
or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=c5a68051d3d81fc964448454cd0310f81f5b4366ed6bd5ad
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 10:13:37.684 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[W 10:13:39.111 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20231030101332 (::1) 20.260000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled11.ipynb?kernel_name=my_env
[I 10:13:39.117 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 38983398-bb22-4527-a438-6703c9caef6e, name: my_env
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
```

I have searched extensively through stackoverflow and Jupyter notebook stackoverflow threads and tried every suggestion I could found that has worked for someone in both places. I have downgraded tornado, and tried to create a new environment and uninstall then reinstall jupyter notebook, but nothing has worked so far. I have also downloded the newest version of anaconda and python and reinstalled both to no avail.(I am running windows 10.)

**Update**

I have since removed the environment I created following one of the suggestions given on stackoverflow, using "jupyter kernelspec uninstall my_env". After that, when I attempted to launch jupyter notebook form command line again, I got these different error messages:

```
[W 11:42:24.708 NotebookApp] Loading JupyterLab as a classic notebook (v6) extension.
[I 2023-10-30 11:42:24.718 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2023-10-30 11:42:24.719 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 11:42:26.388 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\arena
[I 11:42:26.389 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 11:42:26.389 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=cbd196e87cc8774ac3658cb2246c322911b8e11c895f9f10
[I 11:42:26.389 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=cbd196e87cc8774ac3658cb2246c322911b8e11c895f9f10
[I 11:42:26.389 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 11:42:26.418 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/arena/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1836-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=cbd196e87cc8774ac3658cb2246c322911b8e11c895f9f10
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=cbd196e87cc8774ac3658cb2246c322911b8e11c895f9f10
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 11:42:32.590 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[I 11:42:34.876 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 5894b3d1-7185-4445-b150-14740c19d257, name: python3
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Exception in thread IOPub:
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 85, in _thread_main
    self.io_loop.run_sync(_start_event_gc)
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 521, in run_sync
    self.start()
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 195, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1884, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\selectors.py", line 323, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\arena\anaconda3\Lib\selectors.py", line 314, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
```

Hope someone in this community could help me and suggest what I can try next... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by referring to this thread:

[Jupyter Notebook | Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572832/jupyter-notebook-bad-address-c-projects-libzmq-src-epoll-cpp100)

thanks to the suggestion of a friend :)

The root cause appeared to be I have used my VPN in stealth mode and it has changed my winsocket setting. The solution is a command line run of

`netsh winsock reset`

Though the symptom was Jupyter notebook not able to connect to python kernel, the tell tale error message apparently was the "bad address" ones.

I am posting this just in case anyone in the future have the same problem...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).