# How can I start and build a jupyter notebook

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, jupyter

I was trying to start my AI project and needed to build a jupyter notebook.
I performed these steps:

- downloads anaconda for windows (I previously haven't python)
- install anaconda (so registered it as python 3.11)
- get command prompt from pytorch.org and run
- open anaconda prompt (tried both user and administrator) and typed as eithor `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:\WorkPlace2\PyTorch`
  (folder opened without error)
- I trigger new and create an *.ipynb file.
  Then `connecting to server` appears and soon changes as `not connected`

But I got the following error message in cmd:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=D:\WorkPlace2\PyTorch

  _   _          _      _
 | | | |_ __  __| |__ _| |_ ___
 | |_| | '_ \/ _` / _` |  _/ -_)
  \___/| .__/\__,_\__,_|\__\___|
       |_|

Read the migration plan to Notebook 7 to learn about the new features and the actions to take if you are using extensions.

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html

Please note that updating to Notebook 7 might break some of your extensions.

[W 07:59:00.262 NotebookApp] Loading JupyterLab as a classic notebook (v6) extension.
[W 2024-02-22 07:59:00.262 LabApp] 'notebook_dir' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2024-02-22 07:59:00.262 LabApp] 'notebook_dir' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2024-02-22 07:59:00.278 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-02-22 07:59:00.278 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 07:59:03.153 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: D:\WorkPlace2\PyTorch
[I 07:59:03.153 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 07:59:03.153 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=924b87be561de5a84ea8a7caade9de736b0b813d2c4a7fa2
[I 07:59:03.153 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=924b87be561de5a84ea8a7caade9de736b0b813d2c4a7fa2
[I 07:59:03.153 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 07:59:03.215 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Elon/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-6572-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=924b87be561de5a84ea8a7caade9de736b0b813d2c4a7fa2
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=924b87be561de5a84ea8a7caade9de736b0b813d2c4a7fa2
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[I 07:59:11.053 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 6ad7a0f8-e1fc-4aaa-a62e-cc10f1aee0f1, name: python3
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Exception in thread IOPub:
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 85, in _thread_main
    self.io_loop.run_sync(_start_event_gc)
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 521, in run_sync
    self.start()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 195, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1884, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\selectors.py", line 323, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\selectors.py", line 314, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 723, in start
    self.kernel.start()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 223, in start
    super().start()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 553, in start
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.poll_control_queue(), control_loop.asyncio_loop)
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 926, in run_coroutine_threadsafe
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(callback)
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 806, in call_soon_threadsafe
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Elon\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Parent appears to have exited, shutting down.
```

I tried to uninstall anaconda and restarted system and reinstalled anaconda.
But I can't solve that problem.
Before I reinstall my system, I tried this and there was no problem.
But now, I can't find the reason.

Comment: Elon, you'd use Anaconda to open Jupyter since you isntalled it with that. Did you try the routes described [here](https://clouds.eos.ubc.ca/~phil/docs/problem_solving/02-Jupyter-Notebooks/02.04-Opening-a-Jupyter-Notebook.html#:~:text=Open%20a%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20with%20Anaconda%20Navigator,-One%20additional%20way&text=Open%20Anaconda%20Navigator%20using%20the,%E2%80%93%3E%20%5BAnaconda%20Navigator%5D.&text=A%20Jupyter%20file%20browser%20will%20open%20in%20a%20web%20browser%20tab.&text=%3E%20%5BPython%203%5D-,A%20new%20notebook%20will%20open%20as,tab%20in%20your%20web%20browser.)?

Comment: When you asked your question, you were told *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered. Also, as I mentioned in your [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428218/2029983), there is an [edit] feature to add things like errors.

Comment: I see. Windows can be tricky to install & use Python and Jupyter especially if there was previous versions on the machine that weren't cleaned out before others added. Your last indication though seems more promising than you originally indicated. Jupyter is at least running.  I still don't get what you meat by, " Before I reinstall my system, I tried this and there was no problem. But now, I can't find the reason"? Any chance you can use Windows Subsystem in Linux and install the Anaconda Distribution there and start from there? Otherwise cleaning up better & reinstalling is the way.

Comment: @Wayne, Actaully I've never used other Subsystems.
The only thing I did after I reinstalled my system, I downloaded and installed python 3.12.2 and installed anaconda. Then I tried to build jupyter project I coded in the previous system. But I can't. So I thought that the python version is higher than anaconda and so I removed python3.12.2 and installed python3.11.8 and tried.
Still I couldn't and I removed python and only used anaconda.
Any method can't help me.

Comment: The new Python is probably where you went wrong. Ideally start with a clean system and then you install Anconda Distribution and then for anything Python or Jupyter related you only use Anaconda/conda subsequently because by choosing that you made it your primary package manager, which is good because it has features like environments and project management once you learn how it wants you to work. So reading what you did seems to suggest you installed super new Python before Anaconda and you weren't adding Python 3.12 in via an Anaconda environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook | Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572832/jupyter-notebook-bad-address-c-projects-libzmq-src-epoll-cpp100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because of the system environment path.
If you previously have installed other python-related programs such as PyCharm, that may be the reason.
Check here [Why (or why not) Add anaconda to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664293/why-or-why-not-add-anaconda-to-path).
If you have installed Pycharm, then try uninstalling PyCharm and reinstall anaconda.
If that doesn't solve your problem, you may even try reinstalling your windows system.

Another approach can be VPN Server.
Check [Jupyter Notebook | Bad address (C:\projects\libzmq\src\epoll.cpp:100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572832/jupyter-notebook-bad-address-c-projects-libzmq-src-epoll-cpp100)
That is may be another solution.

Comment: The second approach solve my problem. Thank you @Roman.

Comment: By second approach, did you mean uninstalling PyCharm and then reinstalling Anaconda?

Comment: PyCharm isn’t a Python distribution, so I don’t see how installing, uninstalling or reinstalling it would affect this issue.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I mean the last one.

Comment: @ElonMusk And I mean the author of this answer, not your comment.